# Compartir eje entre dos subplots y modificar estilos de gráfico tipo stem

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estoy intentando personalizar/modificar la siguiente grafica que contiene 3 subplots:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como puedo:

1. Unir los subplots 2 y 3 tal que compartan el mismo eje-x (`f [Hz]` y que no haya espacio vertical entre ellos (`hspace = 0.0`).
2. Personalizar los subplots 2 y 3. Aquellos generados con `stem` de tal manera que pueda elegir yo mismo los colores, marcadores, opacidad, el tamaño de los marcadores, las lineas verticales y la linea roja que aparece como `baseline`.

Adjunto el código que estoy empleando a continuación:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,1)

ax[0].plot(t, y, color='red', label='MATHChannel')
ax[0].grid(True)
ax[0].set_xlabel('time [s]')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Amplitude [V]')
ax[0].legend(loc='best')

ax[1].stem(freqs, sp.real, markerfmt='x', label='Re(FFT)', use_line_collection=True)
ax[1].stem(freqs, sp.imag, markerfmt='o', label='Im(FFT)', use_line_collection=True)
ax[1].set_xlim(-20,20)
ax[1].set_xlabel('f [Hz]')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Amplitude [V]')
ax[1].grid(True)
ax[1].legend(loc='best')

ax[2].grid(True)
ax[2].stem(freqs, phase_newdeg, label='Sample name', use_line_collection=True)
ax[2].set_xlim(-20,20)
ax[2].set_xlabel('f [Hz]')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Phase [deg]')
ax[2].legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que los dos subplots compartan el eje x debes especificarlo mediante el argumento `sharex` de `plt.subplot()` o `plt.subplots`.

Además deberás eliminar las marcas y etiquetas del eje `x` del segundo subplot, lo que puedes conseguir con `Axis.tick_params`.

Para poder eliminar el espaciado entre los dos últimos vas a necesitar usar "grids anidados". Puedes conseguirlo con `matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec` y . `matplotlib.gridspec.FromSubplotSpec`.

En cuanto a modificar la lineas, marcadores y línea base de stem, lo que no puedas especificar mediante [`inefmt` ,`markerfmt` y `basefmt` del constructor](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html) puedes hacerlo conservando referencias a cada componente (retornados por `stem`) y luego usar `matplotlib.pyplot.setp`:

```
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax3.stem(
    freqs, phase_newdeg, label='Sample name', use_line_collection=True
    )
plt.setp(baseline, "color", "purple")
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')
plt.setp(markerline, "color", "green")
```

Todo junto:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np


t = np.arange(18)
y = np.random.randint(0, 20, 18)
freqs = [-19, -16, -12, -10, -8, -6,-4, -3, 0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
sp = np.array(
    [3.14j, 4.14j, 3.18j, 3.20j, 5.14j, 6.14j, 7.10j, 4.5j, 6.10j, 
     4.3j, 2.4j, 1.18j, 3.7j, 2.12j, 3.14j, 1.4j, 2.17j, 5.1j]
    )
phase_newdeg = np.random.randint(0, 20, 18)


gs_gen = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1, 1.7], hspace=0.3) 
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec=gs_gen[0])
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=gs_gen[1])

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs2[0, 0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs2[1, 0], sharex=ax2)

ax1.plot(t, y, color='red', label='MATHChannel')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_xlabel('time [s]')
ax1.set_ylabel('Amplitude [V]')
ax1.legend(loc='best')

ax2.stem(
    freqs, sp.real, markerfmt='x', linefmt='C2-',
    label='Re(FFT)', use_line_collection=True
    )

ax2.stem(freqs, sp.imag, markerfmt='o', label='Im(FFT)', use_line_collection=True)
ax2.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax2.set_ylabel('Amplitude [V]')
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.legend(loc='best')
ax2.tick_params(
    axis='x', which='both', bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False
    ) 

ax3.grid(True)
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax3.stem(
    freqs, phase_newdeg, label='Sample name', use_line_collection=True
    )
plt.setp(baseline, "color", "purple")
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')
plt.setp(markerline, "color", "green")

ax3.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax3.set_xlabel('f [Hz]')
ax3.set_ylabel('Phase [deg]')
ax3.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, con estos consejos ya puedo seguir modificando estilos. Además por si a alguien le ayuda o le clarifica aun más las cosas, tambien se puede usar `plt.setp(stemlines, linestyle='dotted', color="springgreen", alpha=0.3)`, en lugar de `plt.setp(stemlines, 'linestyle', 'dotted')`. Incluyo este comentario, porque ha sido el único punto que me ha costado un poco más. ¡Gracias!

Comment: sabrias como se podria reproducir este mismo ejemplo, pero que el plot correspondiente a Phase [deg] o 'ax3' tenga un height_ratio diferente? Por ejemplo que el height_ratio del ax3, sea = 0.2 y los demas tal y como están?